# matplotlib: horizontal labels as style

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

Is there a parameter to force horizontal labels **in an mplstyle file? and/or using rcParams**?

I'm currently using `ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(rotation=0)` at plot construction. I'd like a permanent style or setting. Thanks!

Default look (with `x_compat=True` in a pandas dataframes):

[image]

Desired look:

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': {0: '1950-01-01', 1: '1960-01-02', 2: '1970-01-03', 3: '1980-01-04', 4: '1990-01-05'}, 'Value': {0 : 0, 1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 1, 4: 0}})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df = df.set_index('Date', drop=False)

f, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot(ax=ax, x='Date', x_compat=True)
#ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(rotation=0)
plt.show()
```

I looked in there, but may have missed it:

[customizing-with-matplotlibrc-files](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#)

[matplotlib_configuration_api.html](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/matplotlib_configuration_api.html?highlight=rcparams#matplotlib.rcParams)

Comment: The default rotation in Matplotlib _is_ with no rotation.  You are using pandas ticking to get the rotation. Always be aware that with df.plot you are no longer using pure matplotlib, but rather pandas wrapper of Matplotlib.

Comment: Thanks Jody, you're right. The default `pandas` settings are typically quite good, but I'm just not fond of the slanted labels. I'm building a style file and would like to make sure the labels are horizontal even if I use the pandas wrapper. I couldn't see the parameter in the `matplotlib` docs, but haven't thoroughly tested every option yet! :-)

Comment: yes but the point is that it doesn’t matter what you put in the Matplotlib style file, pandas is overwriting it, so you will need a pandas setting

Comment: Oh! Well I don't need the `pandas` wrapper: but is there a parameter to control the rotation of the labels as a style? Thanks.

Comment: Not that I know of, but the rotation you want _is the default_.

Comment: Thanks Jody! This answers my question, even if somewhat underwhelming. Please do add an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question to put the matter to rest.

**No, there isn't.**

[as of January 2022] There is no way to control tick label rotation via a style. This is because the `pandas` plot wrapper resets the rotation parameter. To quote from  `pandas/doc/source/user_guide/visualization.rst`,

> pandas includes automatic tick resolution adjustment for regular
> frequency time-series data. For limited cases where pandas cannot
> infer the frequency information (e.g., in an externally created
> twinx), you can choose to suppress this behavior for alignment
> purposes.
> [...]
> Using the x_compat parameter, you can suppress this behavior

Despite the wording here --- namely "alignment purposes" ---, setting `x_compat=True` does not reset the rotation parameter back to its `matplotlib` default of 0, as I'd incorrectly expected.

There seem to be mainly two ways around this:

1. Use `matplotlib` directly without `pandas`.
2. Reset the rotation inside the `pandas` plot call. This may be done
   the `pandas` way [See Vishnudev's answer] with `df.plot(... rot=0...)` or the `matplotlib` way [See my OP] with an axis object
   setting `ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(rotation=0)`.

Source and Thanks to: **Jody Klymak** in comments and **Marco Gorelli** at [Github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/45367#event-5896057539).

Answer (score 1):

Use parameter `rot` from `df.plot`

```
df.plot(ax=ax, x='Date', x_compat=True, rot=0)
```

Comment: Nice to know about this other way! How would I set this parameter globally -- as a style -- not at plot creation?  I've added bold style around the first sentence above, to emphasize the nature of my question. Thanks!